# Read and Write with java from one file to another

Tags: java

How do I read the following information from a txt file and write just the numbers to another text file using Java? I have it displaying to the console but it will not write to the file also.

> Jones 369218658389641
>   Smith 6011781008881301
>   Wayne 5551066751345482
>   Wines 4809134775860430
>   Biggie    9925689541232325
>   Luke  7586425896325410
>   Brandy    4388576018410707
>   Ryan  2458912425860439

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a File instance
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("accounts.txt");
    // Create a Scanner for the file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    // Read data from a file
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String accountName = input.next();
        Long cardNumber = input.nextLong();
//this is where I want to write just the numbers to a file called cardnums.txt          
        file = new java.io.File("cardnums.txt"); 
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file); 
        output.println(cardNumber);
        System.out.println(cardNumber);
    }
    // Close the file
    input.close();

}
}
```

I got it now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a File instance
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("accounts.txt");
    // Create a Scanner for the file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    // Read data from a file
    file = new java.io.File("cardnums.txt"); 
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file); 
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String accountName = input.next();
        Long cardNumber = input.nextLong();
//this is where I want to write just the numbers to a file called credit.txt            
        output.println(cardNumber);
        System.out.println(cardNumber);
    }
    // Close the file
    input.close();
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What does cardnums.txt contain in the end ? Is it blank ?

Comment: *Must* you use java? The command line version is trivial.

Comment: @Bohemian It must be an assignment

Comment: It should contain the numbers.

Comment: 369218658389641   
6011781008881301   
5551066751345482   
4809134775860430   
9925689541232325   
7586425896325410   
4388576018410707   
2458912425860439

Comment: It is an assignment. No response all week from the instructor.

Comment: move your file and output assignment lines before loop. and also close the output

Comment: one cc number per line, it works like that on the console but not in the file.

Comment: You should open the file once before the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
```

First of all why are you everytime calling this in loop with same filename?

Secondly, once you define it outside loop,

Call flush() on outputstream object and close if not null (preferabbly in finally block) after loop.

```
if(output!=null) {
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1-liner:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("cardnums.txt"), () ->
   Files.lines(Paths.get("accounts.txt"))
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D", ""))
    .collect(toList())
    .iterator());
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>